# filter_input a $_POST array

Tags: php, arrays, post, filter-input

I have a problem. I want all data sended from the html from by POST method to filter_input into array.

for example when i'll do:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
```

it's printing:

```
array(
    ['forename'] = 'Tomasz',
    ['surname'] = 'Greber'
)
```

but using $_POST directly is not a good practice. Is it possible to:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'something_to_get_post_array_not_directly');
```

thanks for help.

Comment: "using $_POST directly is not a good practice." -  All depends :)

Comment: You can use "Request" from symfony to access data in POST request. For example http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html

And this again depends. For now depends on framework that you are using...